# my gridview in asp.net is working only if i give all value for parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

while configuration sqldatasouce1 IN ASP.NET i used sql statement where sql statement is working well in Test Query THE statement is as follows

```sql
SELECT 
    Name, Gender, Cast, Qualification, Occupation, Country, Age 
FROM  
    Registration 
WHERE 
    (Gender = @gender OR @gender IS NULL) 
    AND (Cast = @cast OR @cast IS NULL) 
    AND (Country = @country OR @country IS NULL) 
    AND (Age >= @Age OR @Age IS NULL) 
    AND (Age <= @Age2 OR @Age2 IS NULL)
```

in my design view I have 1 dropdownbox for gender 1 for cast 1 textbox to select age from another textbox to but it's not working when I run the design. It's working only when I fill all values for parameter.

here is my asp source code

```html
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="PatnerSearch.aspx.vb" 
     Inherits="PatnerSearch" %>

        <%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
    namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 90px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 122px">

        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Gender</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddgender" runat="server" DefaultValue=" " AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Cast</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddcast" runat="server" DefaultValue=" " AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Sunni</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Shai</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Madhvi</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Mamens</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Age</td>
                <td>
                    From:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;To:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Country</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddcountries" runat="server" DefaultValue=" " AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Afghanistan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Akrotiri</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Albania</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Algeria</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>American Samoa</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Andorra</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Angola</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Anguilla</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Antarctica</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Antigua and Barbuda</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Argentina</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Armenia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Aruba</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Ashmore and Cartier Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Australia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Austria</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Azerbaijan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bahamas, The</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bahrain</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bangladesh</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Barbados</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bassas da India</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Belarus</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Belgium</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Belize</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Benin</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bermuda</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bhutan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bolivia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bosnia and Herzegovina</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Botswana</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bouvet Island</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Brazil</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>British Indian Ocean Territory</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>British Virgin Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Brunei</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bulgaria</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Burkina Faso</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Burma</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Burundi</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Cambodia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Cameroon</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Canada</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Cape Verde</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Cayman Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Central African Republic</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Chad</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Chile</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>China</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Christmas Island</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Clipperton Island</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Cocos (Keeling) Islands</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Colombia</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Comoros</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Congo, Democratic Republic of the</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Congo, Republic of the</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Europe</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>UK</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>USA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Germany</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Pakistan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bangladesh</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Srilanka</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Nepal</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>China</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Japan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>UAE</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>KSA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>South Africa</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Hong Kong</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
    <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" 
                    SortExpression="Gender" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Cast" HeaderText="Cast" SortExpression="Cast" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Qualification" HeaderText="Qualification" 
                    SortExpression="Qualification"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Occupation" HeaderText="Occupation" 
                    SortExpression="Occupation" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" 
                    SortExpression="Country" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1ConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT Name, Gender, Cast, Qualification, Occupation, Country, Age FROM Registration WHERE (Gender = @gender OR @gender IS NULL) AND (Cast = @cast OR @cast IS NULL) AND (Country = @country OR @country IS NULL) AND (Age &gt;= @Age OR @Age IS NULL) AND (Age &lt;= @Age2 OR @Age2 IS NULL)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddgender" Name="Gender" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddcast" Name="Cast" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddcountries" Name="country" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtfrom" Name="Age" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtto" Name="Age2" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My button event is as below

```vb
Partial Class PatnerSearch
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this problem . Regards Sana.

Comment: I updated my initially wrong answer. My new answer should help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: sorry, I first misunderstood your problem.

The solution to *your* problem, however, is simple.

Just set **CancelSelectOnNullParameter** on your SqlDataSource to **False**

Comment: Thank you Thank you thank you very much, i been trying and surfing everywhere on internet for this solution. it has been solved. Sana

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter has a property named defaultvalue, you can try set that to "" and change the query like  (Gender = @gender OR @gender ="") and so on.

Comment: i am afraid its showing an error as follows, an object or column name is missing or empty. for Select into statement, verify each column has name. for other statements, look for empty alias names, aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: Thank you for you help. but i found answer by Just set CancelSelectOnNullParameter on your SqlDataSource to False. thanks